# Unable to Install Microsoft Azure Backup Server

Tags: azure

I've been having a problem for the past two days trying install Microsoft Azure Backup Server... I'm very close.

The installation always fails to install the SQL server as shown in the image.

The error logs state:

On a domain controller, you cannot use the built-in Windows service accounts (Local Service or Network Service) as service accounts for Reporting Services

[image]

Comment: are you installing on a domain controller?

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for responding. Yes, I am installing on a domain controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of Azure Backup Server on a domain controller is not supported - see [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup).

[image]

I imagine this is primarily due to the reason you encountered, that installing SQL on a domain controller is also not supported. You will need to use another machine.

Comment: Sam, I didn't realise it wasn't possible to install on a domain controller Thanks